# How can I use the variable in the gs file as the input value in the HTML file in Google Apps script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

The variable fieldName for testGetFieldName function is located at Code.gs

I want to insert it into the input value of the index.html file.

But if I open Sidebar using testSetValue, the value comes out as undefiend.

How can I get the variable 'Account' to come out with Value?

The code I wrote is as follows.

```
//code.gs
function testGetFieldName(){
  var fieldName = 'Account';
  return fieldName;
}

function testSetValue(){
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  var output = html.evaluate()
      .setTitle('MySidebar')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(output);
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id ='textValue' name='textValue' value=''/>
   <script>
     document.getElementById('textValue').setAttribute('value',google.script.run.testGetFieldName());
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

##### From:

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
var output = html.evaluate()
```

##### To:

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
html.value = testGetFieldName();
var output = html.evaluate()
```

#### HTML side:

##### From:

```
document.getElementById('textValue').setAttribute('value',google.script.run.testGetFieldName());
```

##### To:

```
document.getElementById('textValue').setAttribute('value', '<?= value ?>');
```

#### Note:

- If you want to use `google.script.run`, how about the following modification?

  - From

    ```
      document.getElementById('textValue').setAttribute('value',google.script.run.testGetFieldName());
    ```
  - To

    ```
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
        document.getElementById('textValue').setAttribute('value', e);
      }).testGetFieldName();
    ```

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: I checked that it works as I wanted. Thank you!!

Comment: @whytili Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's a best practice to separate your HTML,CSS,JavaScript files.

## References

[HtmlService Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#code.gs)